# Batch file that opens 2 files with different extensions

Tags: batch-file

I use a program that opens `.nc` files and sends them to a machine and I need a label file to open when that happens.

The two files that are named the same with different extensions.
Eg: `test.nc` and `test.ljd`.

When `test.nc` is open by the program I need test.ljd to open
Is this possible with batch files? Or is it possible at all?

Comment: What is the name of the program that opens `.nc` files? And what is the name of the program that opens `.ljd` files?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, which starts `Notepad` but replace `Notepad` with the name of your application that can read these files:

```
@echo off
set file1=%1%.nc
set file2=%1%.ljd
echo Processing %file1%
echo Processing %file2%
start notepad %file1%
start notepad %file2%
```

Save this file as `GO.BAT` then you can type

```
GO test
```

and it will open `test.nc` in one instance of Notepad and `test.ljd` in another Notepad at the same time.

Comment: I quite new to batch files

Comment: I quite new to batch files where would I be typing "GO test? Also the program I'm using I load in a list of .nc file names then it transfers them one by one